# persistence of variables in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I know this question is simplistic. I have been googling trying to wrap my head around variables in web development (specifically ASP.net) but I guess I just don't know where to begin the learning process.

Coming from desktop application development, I know that a variable, so long as it is defined in the correct scope will persist until it is no longer needed (application shutdown, method finishes executing etc.). However, in ASP.NET, what happens to variables?

For example, suppose user A navigates to a web form whose code behind looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
int a = 1;
}
```

when is "a" no longer accessible? If the user posts the form, can I still use "a" knowing that it will be persisted from the last page load? 
If yes, until when does "a" persist?
If no, how can I make it persist?

I am sure there is a lot to read about this subject where to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will persist until Page_Load has finished much like any other normal variable declared in a function.

If you want a variable that will be accessible at any time whilst the page is open you will want to declare outside of any functions, near the start of the Page class.

```
protected int a = 1

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int b = a //b now equals 1
    a = 2; //a now equals 2 and will be referenced as so in any other function.
}
```

Now if you refresh the page it will be reset to 1 and then set to 2 again. If you are using user input to change the value of `a` then you will want to store `a` in Session when the user action needs to change the value of it.

Example:

```
protected function UserClicksAButton()
{
    a = Convert.ToInt32(SomeTextBox.Text);
    Session["A"] = a;
}
```

Then at page load you could check to see if Session["A"] is null, if it's not then set `a = (int)Session["A"];`

Or you could use global variables which are available site wide: You can find out more about global variables at: http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Ok, if I declare it outside, until when will it be accessible? Until the user navigates to another page or until he leaves the server completely? Also, if I declare it there, will the variable be accessible for another user? Or will each user have their own variable?

Comment: Neither, a is only accessible within it's own page. If you want to access A from another page you can either store in it session (See my updated answer) or use Global Variables: http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet

Comment: Also @bob each user has their own variables, they are not shared between users - that would cause all sorts of problems! ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I need to get to reading but this is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

> Coming from desktop application development...

ASP.NET is no different.  You're still using methods, classes, objects, etc.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int a = 1;
}
```

> when is "a" no longer accessible?

You're in the scope of a method.  `a` will fall out of scope when the control flow exits the method.  This is *exactly the same* as desktop applications.

If `a` is a class-level member value then it would remain in memory as long as that object instance is in memory.  If it's a static value then it would remain in memory as long as that static context is loaded.  And so on.

One thing that's often surprising to people new to ASP.NET (which you may have *intended* to ask), is that `Page` objects don't stay in memory between requests.  So if you set a class-level value when you load a page, the next time a request comes to that page (such as clicking a button to invoke a post-back), that value has been lost.  If you think about it, it becomes obvious why this happens.  Imagine the memory requirements for any significant system if all pages needed to *stay in memory* for long periods of time.

Instead, web requests are inherently stateless.  Objects maintain state, so a stateless system isn't going to maintain objects.  So if you want to retain a value across multiple requests then you need to persist it somewhere *outside the object*.  You have a lot of options of where to persist state:

- Page values
- Cookies
- Session
- Static values
- Database (or some other external persistence)

There are pros and cons for all of these, and they each have their own lifespan and reliability under different situations, so it's up to you as the developer to determine which state persistence medium is most important for the particular element of state being persisted.

Comment: Don't forget ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

It works pretty much the same as any application, remember that the code as well as the page is compiled down to a class and then executed.

The only exception is if you define static variables, in that case they would live until the app domain recycles, which it may do for a number of reasons so this is not something you should rely on.

If you need to persist values between requests you would use the built in Session and Application objects to store the values.